# Why is my program exiting before main is called?

Tags: c++, boost

When I execute the following program on the my embedded Linux nothing happens:

```
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/lockfree/spsc_queue.hpp>
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/atomic.hpp>

void Test(void)
{
    std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::cout << "init";

    boost::thread producer_thread(Test);

    producer_thread.join();

    std::cout << "end";
}


# ./prog -> nothing happens here
```

The last few lines from strace output are:

```
open("/lib/libboost_thread.so.1.55.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0(\0\1\0\0\0\240\272\0\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
lseek(3, 95536, SEEK_SET)               = 95536
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1200) = 1200
lseek(3, 95226, SEEK_SET)               = 95226
read(3, "A'\0\0\0aeabi\0\1\35\0\0\0\0055T\0\6\3\10\1\t\1\22\4\24\1\25\1"..., 40) = 40
exit_group(1)                           = ?
+++ exited with 1 +++
#
```

The cross compiled libbost_thread is right installed at /lib.

The program exit before main() being called. The program runs normal under my Ubuntu.

Target: ARM with buildroot (sama5d3)

Toolchain: arm-linux-gnueabihf-

Regards

Comment: Wow. This was upvoted? What is _in the program_?!? I mean, all you show is that indeed it loads boost_thread shared library correctly, and then it exits. What would you expect _instead_? And why?

Comment: Hi, the program should create a thread and print a "Hello World". The program exit before main() being called.

Comment: You need to show us _how_ you made it do so. At this point, anyone's best guess is PEBCAK (see [Select Isn't Broken](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault/))

Comment: Hi, I think now it is better explained. Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe as a hint:

Have you linked against libpthread with compile and link option `-pthread` for your target?

If not it can have the same effect as seen in your environment: The prog starts, try to start a new thread, have no threading enabled and call the abort() function. Because abort() simply leave the prog with error in exit code nothing else happens.

Can you also add your compile & link commands for debugging purpose please!

In addition:

Your outputs without `endl` will not be printed because cout is buffered. The buffer will be printed only if you call `flush` or send a `endl`. Maybe you change this in your example.

Hope that helps...

Answer (score 2):

`strace` is a tool that traces system calls. In your example, this consists of calls to `open()`, `lseek()`, and `read()`. Specifically, the snippet that you pasted shows the OS's dynamic library loader opening the `libboost_thread.so.1.55.0` file and reading its contents; nothing more. It doesn't really demonstrate anything about your program except that it is linked against that library.

Comment: I posted the code. Any idea why is it exiting before main() being called?

Comment: Nothing obvious looks amiss. Try running it under a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

The boost library was compiled with arm-linux-gnueabi- (elibc) and the buildroot is compiled with uClibc.